# Selecting and exporting by attribute iteration in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, iteration

I'm trying to do a loop for select and export layers by attribute and name them based on the field value. I've written the script below and it creates the shapefiles which picks up field values as shapefiles' name but they are empty output shapefiles. looks like the query in the select process isn't run.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\temp'

# Create the search cursor
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor('fc', '')

# Iterate through rows in cursor
for row in cursor:
    outfc=r'C:\temp\test'+"\\"+str("{0}".format(row.Project))
    arcpy.Select_analysis("fc",outfc,'"Project"=\'"{0}".format(row.Project)\'')

### Project is the field name which is a String.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is easier to use the triple quote than to try mixing the different types of quotes. In your case the format statement is within the text string, so that it is interpreted as a string.

```
outfc=r'C:\temp\test'+"\\"+ row.Project

arcpy.Select_analysis(infc ,outfc,""" "Project"= '{0}' """.format(row.Project) )
```